# Speed up django rest framework template rendering performance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When i open my list API in browser using `.json` at the end of url(like `http://server/api/staff-list.json`) it works very fast, but when i try to open it without `.json` it sometimes throw 504 error. I think the reason in rendering filters(there are a lot of them). Is there a way to speed up DRF template rendering?

Comment: what you opened in browser is doc page or api data？

Comment: @Hayden api data.

Comment: In normal，the drf process view  use some time to determine   what format used to render response data,I guess the .json will help the drf make decision more quickly.

Comment: @Hayden This is returns raw json without drf template. But i need to render default drf template with api data.

Comment: APIs have no template,Just doc page has template.

Comment: @Hayden So, is this a doc page template or api template [http://www.django-rest-framework.org/img/quickstart.png](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/img/quickstart.png)?

Comment: This is doc page template。

Comment: `REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [ 'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer'] }` see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers